# How to wp_enqueue a second style.css file for responsive design?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

I need to enqueue another .css file in my theme function file for responsive design only, I just do not want to merge styles in one file.
My code for this matter is like this:

```
function mustabox_resources() {

      wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

      wp_enqueue_script(
        'mustascript',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mustascript.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );


      wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri:400,600&amp;subset=arabic', false );

      if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mustabox_resources');
```

So i want to add another wp_enqueue_style to my another css file which is:
responsive.css with the flowing details:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
```

Comment: And your actual problem is what …? How to specify which media the stylesheet is applied for, is described very clearly in the documentation for wp_enqueue_style ...

Comment: I tried what documentation says but did not work because it does not give enough information about 'screen ... media...

Answer (score 0):

Is detailed in the [Wordpress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/#parameters):

```
function mustabox_resources() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('responsive-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/responsive-style.css', array(), '1.000', 'max-width: 800px');

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'mustascript',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mustascript.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );


    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=El+Messiri:400,600&amp;subset=arabic', false );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' )) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mustabox_resources');
```

Anyway, I don't recommend you this separated way. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but why you don`t recommend this separated way? and i tried this but didn't worked

Comment: I don't know why you want the styles in two files, but I don't recommend you this way because there is no need to load two files for this purpose. 
The file is loading anyway despite of the applied media query and this could make the website slower and given that you are developing the project in WordPress there is a lot of stuff loading because plugins, etc.

Regarding the fact that it does not work for you I would need more information to help you, because that code should work...

Comment: Understood, Thanks very much... i made it one file again like you said